# SPWeb.lists[] List does not exist

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, wss

I am running my code under administrative rights that iterates over different site->spweb to check the existance of a list. Strangely and **for some site** the code returns me that list does not exists(exception : List does not exists) Yet i can totally browse the list from browser on the same web
what am i missing here ?
EDIT:Adding Code

```
                    foreach (SPSite s in webApp.Sites)
                    {
                        foreach (SPWeb w in s.AllWebs)
                        {

                         try{
                          SPList sourceList = w.Lists["Ticks and  Cross"];
                          }catch(exception ex){ ..... }

                        }
                        s.Dispose();
                    }
```

All sites has same templates, so there is no chance that list is not ther. For some site i get the sourceList, for other its exception, its really wired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you pass incorrect parameter to Lists[]. You should specify valid guid, title or index of the list. Can you post your code?

Comment: I wish, The list name has spaces thou, should i use %20 instead?

Comment: The list name looks OK - you can use spaces. But I don't see other option, if it fails name should be invalid. I would advise to make some debugging - can you examine Lists collection of the web inside catch (set breakpoint or add debug out put) to see which lists are there?